# Why changing initialRoute according to the async storage value not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Inside my react native App.js file

I want to control the user login state.
Since I am saving the user login state in the local storage using `react native async storage` I wanna change the initial screen according to the value.

So in the app.js useEffect Hook
I have something like this

```
const [initialRoute, setInitialRoute] = useState('AuthChoice');

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getStorageValue() {
      let value;
      try {
        value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
      } catch (e) {
        // handle here
      } finally {
        console.log(value === 'true');
        if (value === 'true') {
          setInitialRoute('Home');
        } else {
          setInitialRoute('AuthChoice');
        }
      }
    }
    getStorageValue();
  }, []);
```

and in the return state meant I am changing screen according to the set state value

```
return (
    <>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={initialRoute}>
            <Stack.Screen
              options={{
                headerShown: false,
              }}
              name="AuthChoice"
              component={AuthChoiceScreen}
            />
```

But the app never led me to `homePage` whenever I goes into app even I logged in at previous session.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that is that the use effect is async and the initial route for the React Navigation is not. Before you load the data from async storage (it is async as the name suggests) the initial route is either set to default or undefined. In this case it will open the

> homePage

wich I assume is the first route you have in your array/object.

**WHAT TO DO?**

You should create a loading component that is parent to the navigation. Put some sort of spinner for the time you get the data from the storage and then use conditional rendering to open the router navigation and pass the initial route as a prop.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
const MainLoader = () => {
  const [initialised, setInitialised] = useState(false)
  const [initialRoute, setInitialRoute] = useState('AuthChoice')

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getStorageValue() {
      let value;
      try {
        value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
      } catch (e) {
        // handle here
      } finally {
        console.log(value === 'true');
        if (value === 'true') {
          setInitialRoute('Home');
        } else {
          setInitialRoute('AuthChoice');
        }
        setInitialised(true)
      }
    }
    getStorageValue();
  }, []);

  return initialised
    ? <Router initialRoute={initialRoute} />
    : <LoadingSpinner />

}

const Router = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={props.initialRoute}>
            <Stack.Screen
              options={{
                headerShown: false,
              }}
              name="AuthChoice"
              component={AuthChoiceScreen}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
    </>
}
```